# What does Close (1) mean in Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, user-experience

I posted a question on Stack Overflow 1 hour ago and I just checked back and found that there is a `close(1)` below my question. It looks something like this:

[image]

When I click on the close button, it directs me to the flag question page to let me flag my question.

What does it mean? I tried to search online, but can't find any explanation.

If it is for closing my question, what is the benefits of that? Questions are asked with the belief the question has value and is worth being answered. I think in most of situations people will not close their own questions.

Comment: It means there is one close vote on that question. It needs 3 to actual close the question. On that particular question the current close vote is: *needs more focus*.

Comment: Users can close their own question as a duplicate. That is handy when their continued research all of a sudden does render a viable duplicate target. Same goes for "typo" like question if their mistake is pointed out in a comment.

Comment: Not to sound overly nitpicky, but the tooltip for the button clearly says "2 more votes are needed to close this question" - that should be pretty easy to grasp the meaning of. That said, Meta *is* the place to ask for clarifications on the matter, no harm done. Also see the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) article on question closure.

Comment: Also also: [MSE FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10582/786798) on question closure

Comment: Speaking of the question you got a close vote on, I do not find the vote appropriate - the reason is reserved for posts that should be multiple questions, cannot be answered without writing a book chapter on the topic, or require the answerer to become a free "code monkey" for the asker. Yours is pretty focused, albeit maybe a duplicate (CSS tag regulars will likely find one soon)

Comment: @OlegValter, Thanks for telling me that!

Comment: The main benefit of closing a question: If the question cannot be answered in a clean and concise manner, closing the question protects it from collecting substandard answers. Remember that Stack Overflow isn't about answering questions. It's about making a database of high quality questions and answers for the benefit of all programmers.

Comment: @OlegValter it is not actually very likely that a CSS question is dupe closed, in my experience. The tag culture is to just answer everything. Only gold badgers tend to dupe close a CSS question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is the button to vote to close a question, which is awarded to you as part of the [View and cast close/reopen votes on your own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) privilege. (Awarded at 250 reputation.)

People with 3000 reputation or more, will see this button [on every question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) (that isn't locked or already closed).

The `(1)` is the current number of close votes that are cast on the question. If you click on that close button, it will open a modal that shows you the close reasons that can be selected and the [number of times those reasons are chosen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JF7lv.png). (No worries, you wont actually cast any votes unless you explicitly click on the "Vote to close" button.)

More information about closing and reopening can be found in the [cast close and reopen votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) privilege help page.

> If it is for closing my question, what is the benefits of that?

I assume the primary reason is to allow users to see close votes that are cast on their own questions. This gives you the opportunity to address them before your question gets actually closed. It also allows you to close your own question as a duplicate, in case you find one on Stack Overflow after you asked your question.